# How to inject SessionFactory when persistence unit is defined?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a fully working Spring 4 + Hibernate application. Hibernate is configured via `<persistence-unit>`... My unit test does all DB-related work without a problem. But now I want to access Hibernate session; to do that I should inject `SessionFactory`. How to inject it considering the following configuration?

I know I could define a bean like `LocalSessionFactoryBean` but don't know how to configure it. (I want no duplicated aconfiguration also.)

MyTest.java

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:META-INF/spring/test-context.xml" })
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class, TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class})
public class MyTest {

    @Inject
    SessionFactory sessionFactory; // want it injected

}
```

test-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany"/>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <bean id="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="my-persistence-unit"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="..." version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="my-persistence-unit" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/my</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.mycompany.entity.Document</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm"/>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: You are using JPA so you should use an `EntityManager` not a `SessionFactory`.

Comment: Why does not  `@Inject SessionFactory sessionFactory` work? Is there any error?

Comment: Seems this is the same thing as you want: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/130853-injecting-hibernate-sessionfactory-when-using-localcontainerentitymanagerfactorybean

Answer (score 0):

Because I use JPA I should inject `EntityManager`, not `SessionFactory`. This solved my task finally.

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;
...
entityManager.refresh(obj); // working with H-session
...
```

This is exactly by the @m-deinum's comment; if he will add his own answer then I'll mark it as decision.